# Python socket connection timeout

Tags: python, sockets

I have a socket that I want to timeout when connecting so that I can cancel the whole operation if it can't connect yet it also want to use the makefile for the socket which requires no timeout.

Is there an easy way to do this or is this going to be a difficult thing to do?

Does python allow a reset of the timeout after connected so that I can use makefile and still have a timeout for the socket connection

Comment: Yes, python does allow timeout resetting. You can even set a different timeout after makefile. I have tested on linux and windows.

Answer (score 146):

You just need to use the socket [`settimeout()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) method before attempting the `connect()`, please note that after connecting you must `settimeout(None)` to set the socket into blocking mode, such is required for the makefile .
Here is the code I am using:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(10)
sock.connect(address)
sock.settimeout(None)
fileobj = sock.makefile('rb', 0)
```

Comment: For information, the timeout must be expressed in seconds.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using Python2.6 or newer, it's convenient to use [`socket.create_connection`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection)

```
sock = socket.create_connection(address, timeout=10)
sock.settimeout(None)
fileobj = sock.makefile('rb', 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

For setting the Socket timeout, you need to follow these steps:

```
import socket
socks = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socks.settimeout(10.0) # settimeout is the attr of socks.
```

Comment: Do note in version 3.7.x and perhaps earlier there is also a `sockets.setdefaulttimeout(10.0)` which I think is used by all newly created sockets library objects that take timeouts.

Comment: Adding to @DevPlayer note, you need to call sockets.setdefaulttimeout(10.0) before creating the socket. Tested with Python 3.10.6.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
try:
   import socket  
   socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   socket.settimeout(10)
except socket.error:
    print("Nope !!!")
```