# Python Try and Except - The script get hung on the except

Tags: python

I have a small script that will check to see if a list of devices are either ssh or telnet enable.
Here is my code:

```
import socket
import sys
file = open('list', 'r')
file = file.readlines()

list = []

for i in file:
    i=i.replace('\n','')
    list.append(i)
for i in list:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect((i, 22))
        s.shutdown(2)
        s.close()
        print (i+' SSH ')
    except:
        try:
            s.connect((i, 23))
            s.shutdown(2)
            s.close()
            print (i+' Telnet')
        except:
            print (i + 'disable')
            pass
```

When I get an exception, I have to hit ctrl + c to go to the next device. What are am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You should not catch *all* exceptions. Catch specific exceptions only instead.

Comment: Try `except Exception as e` and then figure out the type of `e` by printing `type(e)`. Also try printing before each statement in your `try` block so you know where you're getting stuck.

Comment: You should not use list as a name since it a built in name.

Comment: One word: [`nmap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try adding a [timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432102/python-socket-connection-timeout)?

```
import socket
import sys
with open('list', 'r') as f:# file is a global class

    # per default it reads the file line by line, 
    # readlines() loads the whole file in memory at once, using more memory
    # and you don't need the list.
    for i in f:
        i=i.replace('\n','')
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(10)
        try:
            s.connect((i, 22))
            s.shutdown(2)
            s.close()
            print (i+' SSH ')
        except:
            try:
                s.connect((i, 23))
                s.shutdown(2)
                s.close()
                print (i+' Telnet')
            except:
                print (i + 'disable')
                pass
```

setting up a time out closes the stream after a timeout, otherwise it blocks forever.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really run the code because I don't have the `list` file you open on my machine. Still made few edits, any difference?

```
import socket
import sys
file = open('list', 'r')
file = file.readlines()

list = []

for i in file:
    i=i.replace('\n','')
    list.append(i)
for i in list:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
         s.connect((i, 22))
         s.shutdown(2)
         s.close()
         print (i+' SSH ')
    except:
         s.connect((i, 23))
         s.shutdown(2)
         s.close()
         print (i+' Telnet')
    else:
         print (i + 'disable')
         pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Again I can't really run the code because of lack of the file 'list' (rather misleading..) but I've done some further refactoring and offered up a suggestion.

```
import socket
import sys

with open('list', 'r') as f:
    # Don't call anything 'list' as it is the name for pythons inbuilt type
    # Using `with` will automatically close the file after you've used it.
    content = f.readlines()
    # We can use a list comprehension to quickly strip any newline characters.
    content = [x.replace('\n','') for x in content]

for x in content:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect((x, 22))
        s.shutdown(2)
        s.close()
        print (x+' SSH')
    except:
    # This should catch a specific exception, e.g. TimeoutError etc
    # e.g. `except ConnectionError`
        try:
            s.connect((i, 23))
            s.shutdown(2)
            s.close()
            print (i+' Telnet')
        except:
            print (i + 'disable')
            pass
```

My guess is that the connection is hanging rather than hitting the exception. Maybe due to timeouts as it cannot connect.

Add a timeout option with:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(60)
```