# What is the Python equivalent of RequestConfig in Java?

Tags: java, python, apache, python-2.7, http

I have the following piece of code in Java:

```
RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(10).setConnectTimeout(20).build();
```

How do I achieve the same thing in Python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3432222/3014866

Comment: I have actually looked at that question before. The problem is there is a `settimeout()` function which sets the timeout for socket operations, but I can't seem to find a timeout option for the connection operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3432222/3014866) where is shown how to set `timeout`.

It results from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) that `setSocketTimeout` and `setConnectTimeout` are the same things in Python.

> Note that the `connect()` operation is subject to the timeout setting,
>   and in general it is recommended to call `settimeout()` before calling
>   `connect()` or pass a timeout parameter to `create_connection()`. The
>   system network stack may return a connection timeout error of its own
>   regardless of any Python socket timeout setting.