# Python TCP/IP Communication

Tags: python, tcp, modbus

This is my python modbus tcp communication code and it wait at the this line and than stopping for the connection where is my fault:

```
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
```

(if i use slave program also not working)
At the my client side i am using this code:

```
TCP_IP='10.0.2.15'
TCP_PORT=502
BUFFER_SIZE=39
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
```

This is the master side:

```
# Create a TCP/IP socket
TCP_IP = '10.0.2.2'
TCP_PORT = 502
BUFFER_SIZE = 39
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))



try:

    unitId = 16  # Plug Socket11
    functionCode = 3  # Write coil

    print("\nSwitching Plug ON...")
    coilId = 1
    req = struct.pack('12B', 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, int(unitId), 0x03, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00,
                  0x00)
    sock.send(req)
    print("TX: (%s)" % req)
    rec = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print("RX: (%s)" % rec)
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\nSwitching Plug OFF...")
    coilId = 2
    req = struct.pack('12B', 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, int(unitId), 0x03, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00,
                  0x00)
    sock.send(req)
    print("TX: (%s)" % req)
    rec = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print("RX: (%s)" % rec)
    time.sleep(2)

finally:
    print('\nCLOSING SOCKET')
    sock.close()
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: where is my fault ?

Comment: How specifically is the program not working? What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: i have no error i said program waiting this line and stopping without connection sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the IP address: `10.0.2.2` as stated here [[Connection to LocalHost/10.0.2.2 from Android Emulator timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441481/connection-to-localhost-10-0-2-2-from-android-emulator-timed-out]). 
You can replace `'10.0.2.2'` with `'localhost'` or try to find your `IPv4` address.

To do so type ifconfig in your command prompt if you use Linux or type ipconfig in windows and search for the `IPv4` address.

I used a simple client-server example to run your code and replaced `'10.0.2.2'` with `'localhost'` and everything went fine.

server side:

```
import socket
import struct
import time

TCP_IP = 'localhost'                 
TCP_PORT = 502
BUFFER_SIZE = 39

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
sock, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
try:
    unitId = 16  # Plug Socket11
    functionCode = 3  # Write coil

    print("\nSwitching Plug ON...")
    coilId = 1
    req = struct.pack('12B', 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 
    int(unitId), 0x03, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00,
    0x00)
    while 1:
        sock.send(req)
        print("TX: (%s)" % repr(req))
        rec = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print("RX: (%s)" % repr(rec))
        time.sleep(2)
        break

    print("\nSwitching Plug OFF...")
    coilId = 2
    req = struct.pack('12B', 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 
    int(unitId), 
    0x03, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00,
    0x00)
    while 1:
        sock.send(req)
        print("TX: (%s)" % repr(req))
        rec = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print("RX: (%s)" % repr(rec))
        time.sleep(2)
        break
finally:
    sock.close()
```

client side:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = 'localhost'    
TCP_PORT = 502            
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

data = sock.recv(1024)
print  repr(data)
while 1:
    sock.send(data)
    print("send back to server: (%s)" % repr(data))
    break

data = sock.recv(1024)
print  repr(data)
while 1:
    sock.send(data)
    print("send back to server: (%s)" % repr(data))
    break
sock.close()
```

make sure you run server and client in seperate files/terminals

Comment: I added do stuff here line this : req = struct.pack('12B', 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, int(unitId), 0x03, 0xff, 0xc0, 0x00,
                  0x00)
    sock.send(req) I have this error """  sock.send(req)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
"""

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is "Why is the sock.connect() call hanging?". That's because by default it waits for a connection indefinitely. In other words, the call is 'blocking' by default. If you want to only wait up to 500 milliseconds for a connection, you need to specify this:

```
sock.connect(.5) #wait 500 milliseconds for a connection attempt
```

Also, see [Python socket connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432102/python-socket-connection-timeout)