# Is it possible to set a timeout for socket.close()

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working with sockets and noticed my program gets 'stuck' sometimes when I'm trying to perform a `socket.close()`. Is it possible to set a timeout for how long `socket.close()` is allowed to take before just continuing? Would calling `socket.shutdown()` just end up fixing the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python socket connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432102/python-socket-connection-timeout)

Comment: @KJTHoward that's for `socket.connect()` but it isn't clear if it would work for `socket.close()`