# Python library socket connect_ex, wait time

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to do a port test using the python socket library.

The object uses `connect_ex((ip,port))`, and the result is immediately

displayed in case of success but waits for about 2 minutes in case of failure.

Is there a way to adjust it to 30 seconds?

Comment: Rread this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432102/python-socket-connection-timeout